# How to show border around tooltip chart.js and show y-axis integer value along with text in tooltip title?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, chart.js

i am drawing a line chart using chart.js and showed a tooltip on graph.But i am not able to draw a border around tooltip and in title i want to show text and current y-axis value as title(eg.total count:2 but instead of 2 it showing undefined.Now i removed code from title callback). I am trying for many days but still no luck. Please help me. Here is my code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');          
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
       type: 'line',
       data: {
            labels:["a","b","c"],
            datasets: [{                    
                label: 'Total count',
                lineTension: 0,
                data: [2,4,6],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgba(39,50,139,1)',
                pointBackgroundColor:'rgba(176,179,214,1)',
                pointBorderColor:'rgba(39,50,139,1)',
                pointRadius:5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor:'rgba(39,50,139,1)',
                borderWidth:2
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend:{
                display:false
            },
            chartArea: {
                backgroundColor: '#fff'
            },
            scales: {                   
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true,
                        maxTicksLimit:3
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        color: "black"
                      },
                    ticks: {
                        max:12,
                        maxTicksLimit:12
                    }
                }]
            },              
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {                        
                  title:function(tooltipItem, data) {                         
                  },
                  afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {                      
                     return userNamesResult[tooltipItem.index];                       
                   }
                },
                titleSpacing:0,
                titleMarginBottom:0,
                titleFontColor:'#000',
                backgroundColor: '#f2f3f4',
                bodyFontColor: '#000',
                //bodyFontStyle:'bold',
                bodyFontSize: 14,
                displayColors: false,                   
                borderColor:'#ff0000',
                borderWidth:5,                  
              } 
         }
    });
```

Comment: I removed the whole 'callbacks' part of 'tooltips' from your script and it works. I can see a red border around the tooltip and the text is for example of the center one is 'Total count: 4'. Which version of chart.js are you using?

Comment: @AnikoLitvanyi my chart version is 2.4.0

Comment: I tried it with v2.7.2, can you recheck the issue with this version?

Comment: @AnikoLitvanyi i checked but still it is not working. But somehow i managed it with a custom tooltip. Thank you for your valuble time.